# MATLAB Feval C# client cache issue

Tags: c#, matlab

I need to run MATLAB code in C# application. I have read the [official documentation](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html) to run MATLAB function in my application.

It works but I have a cache issue. 
If I run the MATLAB given code in C#:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 

namespace ConsoleApplication2 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            // Create the MATLAB instance 
            MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp(); 

            // Change to the directory where the function is located 
            matlab.Execute(@"cd c:\temp\example"); 

            // Define the output 
            object result = null; 

            // Call the MATLAB function myfunc
            matlab.Feval("myfunc", 2, out result, 5, 7, "world"); 

            // Display result 
            object[] res = result as object[]; 

            Console.WriteLine(res[0]); 
            Console.WriteLine(res[1]); 
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

with the following matlab function:

```
function [x,y] = myfunc(a,b,c) 
x = a + b; 
y = sprintf('Hello %s',c);
```

If I change `x = a + b;` in `x = a * b;` in MATLAB script function, the application continue to return a+b=12 instead of a*b=35.

How to solve this cache issue?

Comment: Check if rehash toolbox will help you as in https://sourceforge.net/p/mlmechtrade/feature-requests/3/

Comment: Did you recompile the matlab and put results in you project folder?  Where is the matlab dll located on the PC?  From c# you do not run the source .m file.  The matlab source needs to be compiled.